# What is the third number in subscription of Topic in Service Bus Explorer

Tags: subscription

I am using Azure Service Bus Explorer,
What is the third number of Subscription in Service Bus Explorer,
For Example,
topicname
  - Subscriptions
   - SubscriptinName(12,13,0),
the first one(12) is the number of the messages
the second number(13) is the number of the messages in dead letter queue,
what is the third number 0?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is [here](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues/313).

It looks like it displays the `TransferDeadLetterMessageCount`.